# Angular HTML5Mode - Rewrite rule

Tags: angularjs, iis, url-rewriting, angular-ui-router

I'm experiencing a pathing issue when I refresh a tab on my site:

I copied this rewrite rule from github:

```
  <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
```

This works great on a path such as https://www.mywebsite.com/dashboard .

However, when I refresh a path like https://www.mywebsite.com/tab/settings my javascript loads fine, but my css directory is off by 1.

My Scripts path loads correct like so:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/Scripts/angular.js`

However, my CSS is trying to load as :

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/tab/Content/bootstrap.min.css
```

With the /tab/ causing my issue.

My routes:

```
.state('Template',
        {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/SharedViews/Landing/dashboardheader.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('Template.AdminTab',
        {
            url: '/admin',
            views: {
                'container@': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Views/Admin.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('Template.Tab.Company',
        {
            url: '/company',
            views: {
                'container@': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Views/Admin.html'
                },
                'tabs-views@': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Views/Company.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('Template.Tab.Users',
        {
            url: '/users',
            views: {
                'container@': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Views/Admin.html'
                },
                'tabs-views@': {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Views/Users.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

How can I modify the rewrite rule to load css correctly on urls that are 2+ segments deep?

Comment: Check out this link: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: @Kyle That's where I got the url rewrite rule I'm trying, I believe I've implemented the bottom part of the guide, I posted my routes in addition to my url rewrite rule.

Comment: Can you post how you load the css? You probably have `Content/bootstrap.min.css` instead of `/Content/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: how are you loading the css in `index.html`?

Comment: @maurycy It looks like it was as simple as adding a / , however I'm a bit confused then as I'd expect different behavior:  I'm now calling my css as <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/flexslider.css"> and I can refresh my tabbed browsing pages correctly, however I still call my javascript as <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script> .  I was wondering what the difference was, also please post your suggestion as the answer and I'll accept, thank you!

Comment: Adding the / before link to source means it will start resolving the path starting from the domain root level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should have your path as:
 `/Content/bootstrap.min.css`

instead of: 
`Content/bootstrap.min.css`

Putting a '/' in front will resolve the path based on the the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I see the suggestions from @maurycy and up to a point, I agree with it. But this solution has its own limitations. What if you want to deploy your app in a new context i.e. https://www.mywebsite.com/my_new_app.

Now `/Content/bootstrap.min.css` will still point to `https://www.mywebsite.com/bootstrap.min.css`, which will again cause the issue.

In my opinion, if you want to control it, you can use a [base tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). It defines what is the base URL of your website, and your browser will load all the relative URLs (the one which don't start with a `/`) with the base as a prefix to them. Set it in your HTML's `head` tag as follows:

```
<base href="/">
```

Now, all your assets will be loaded relative to this path, regardless of what your current browser URL is. Plus, you're free to specify any context here. For example, if you've deployed your app under `/my_new_app`, simply change the `href` to `/my_new_app/` (don't forget the trailing slash), and the URLs will start loading relative to this path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `/my_new_app/` just worked when don't have port for example for localhost `apache` server as `xamp` or `wamp`, this question related to `IIS` which has `web.config` so it should be `href="/"`

Comment: @Maher - Thanks for your comment, but this solution doesn't consider any server side handling. `base` is just a client-side tag which suggests the browser to resolve URLs relative to the specified path.

Comment: Interesting, I've had <base href="/"/> the whole time, so I needed the / with the base already in there

Comment: @RandomUs1r -- Not sure! So, you're saying that you already defined the base tag and it still didn't help?

Comment: @RandomUs1r -- Did it fix your problem?